# How to assert that all elements in the collection have a property which is equal among them?

Tags: java, testing, junit, hamcrest

I have a collection of Objects (let's say `Car`s). Each car has a property of type `Company` which can be identified by its `id`.

Now I want to assert that all cars in my collection belong to the same company, i.e. each car's company is equal to all the others.

Note, that in my test *I do not know the value of the company ID in advance*. I don't care about the value, the only important thing it that is is the same among all cars.

I would imagine something like:

`assertThat(allCars, Matchers.equalAmongAll(hasProperty("company", hasProperty("id"))));`

**EDIT**: Only Java 7 is available, Java 8 expressions can not be used

Comment: why don't simply loop through the `allCars` collection?

Comment: Of course that is an option, but it's a bit clumsy (especially when going deeper one more level) and I would like to know if there is a more elegant way using the fluent API provided by Hamcrest.

Comment: The second most important thing about UnitTest is (after readability) that they _fail for the right reason_. A handcrafted Matcher may enhance readability but be a cause of failure in unexpected circumstances and this would be a _wrong reason_ to fail...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you, maybe something like this:

```java
int id = allCars.get(0).getId();
List<Car> list = allCars.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == id).collect(Collectors.toList());
assertEquals(list.size(), allCars.size());
```

Comment: I would need another call to go over the companies mapping `allCars.stream().map(car -> car.getCompany()).filter(com -> com.getId() ....` But unfortunately I can not use Java,8 just Java 7, sorry should have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: but you can use the same pattern: loop over the original list, collect all matching cars in a new list and compare the two lists...

Comment: If you have guava lib in your code, you can use it for your purpose. If not - there is no troubles to make it with old style for loop.